# How to allow a specific to access EC2 instance at AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I like to open ssh inbound rule only for an ip from another country.
I have developer in Vietnam. I like to allow access to my instance for his ip in Vietnam.

His ip is, for example, 192.108.0.14.

So I set inbound rule SSH port 22 for ip address 192.108.0.14/32
But he said can't access.

So now I changed to 0.0.0.0/0.
That is not save, I don't like it.

Why I can't allow his ip address to access my EC instance?
What is wrong with my inbound rule?

Comment: It must be work, double check his ip address.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to check

1. Does your EC2 instance live in a public subnet(internet gateway)?
2. What are your NACL rules, do you allow inbound and outbound access?

Answer (score 0):

Your inbound rule is correct, but I'm not sure if they give you the correct public IP, please share him this link http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and ask him for the IP again.